# Is 2abcd always less than aadd + bbdd?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I'm working through the inductive proof under no 6 (http://rgmia.org/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf)

Thanks Janak for the link!

Anyways, from the proof:

$\sum a_i^2 \sum b_i^2 > (\sum a_i b_i)^2$

If we limit ourselves to two values for $a$ and $b$ respectively then:

$(a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2) > (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2$

$a_1^2b_1^2+a_1^2b_2^2 +a_2^2b_1^2 + a_2^2b_2^2 > a_1^2b_1^2 +2a_1a_2b_1b_2 +a_2^2b_2^2$

The first and last terms cancel out, leaving:

$a_1^2b_2^2 +a_2^2b_1^2 > 2a_1a_2b_1b_2 $

....Which seems to be accepted straight off the bat. I've inserted different numbers in the formula, and it seems to work out. But is there a reason (or dare I ask, proof) why this is always the case?

Comment: Your title should be $aacc+bbdd$

Comment: My question is "why" aadd + bbcc is more than 2abcd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you change the sign to $\ge$.  Subtract the right side and you get $a_1^2b_2^2 +a_2^2b_1^2-2a_1a_2b_1b_2=(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)^2$, which is clearly greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(a-b)^2\ge 0$

The square of a number is always non-negative.

Comment: Sure but...neither a,b,c or d "needs" to be negative either.Surely,  aadd + bbcc > 2abcd should hold true no matter the sign of the numbers?

Comment: Yes..it holds true for positive as well as negative values of a,b,c,d.